# Can field names be wordwrapped?

Tags: civievent, forms

Using CiviCRM 4.7.1
Some of the field names in our registration form are so long that, on the form the attendees use, they are truncated. Also on the confirmation messages. Either truncated or overtyping the data. Can the field names be wrapped?
The field names shown are "SS Dance Class - 1st choice" and "... 2nd choice", etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend either:
1) Using Drupal Webform to capture the data (are you on Drupal?)
2) Adding a custom template for this profile
3) Using a custom theme for this page
4) Report this as a bug to be fixed in future versions of Civi.

Comment: We are on Joomla. I don't know where to look for a custom template or theme. How do I report a bug? To whom?

Comment: To report a bug: issues.civicrm.org

To have a custom template made: ask your software developer, or consult with a freelancer (I'll happily do this - john@civifirst.com) or CiviCRM Partner (https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors).

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM inherits most of its look and feel from the CSS code in your CMS's theme - in your case Joomla.  By default, CiviCRM's labels won't do this.  Your Joomla web designer should be able to modify their CSS to prevent this happening.